# How to create multiselect with checkbox and check all and uncheck all using material-ui react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, multi-select

I have create custom component to select multiple option in that we have check all option but we don't have uncheck option. I have created uncheck all option with same select all option but how to change the label name.

**multiSelectWithCheckbox.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Checkbox, InputLabel, ListItemIcon, ListItemText, MenuItem, FormControl, Select } from '@material-ui/core'
import { MenuProps, useStyles } from './multiSelectWithCheckboxUtil'


function MultiSelectWithCheckbox(props) {
    const classes = useStyles()
    const isAllSelected = props.options.length > 0 && props.value.length === props.options.length

    const handleChange = React.useCallback(event => {
        const value = event.target.value
        if (value[value.length - 1] === 'all') {
            props.onChange(props.value.length === props.options.length ? [] : props.options)
            return
        }
        props.onChange(value)
    }, [ props.value ])

    return (
        <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
            <InputLabel id='mutiple-select-label' style={{fontSize: 18}}>{props.label}</InputLabel>
            <Select
                labelId='mutiple-select-label'
                multiple
                value={props.value}
                onChange={handleChange}
                renderValue={React.useCallback(selected => selected.join(', '))}
                MenuProps={MenuProps}
            >
                <MenuItem
                    value='all'
                    classes={{
                        root: isAllSelected ? classes.selectedAll : '',
                    }}
                >
                    <ListItemIcon>
                        <Checkbox
                            classes={{
                                indeterminate: classes.indeterminateColor,
                            }}
                            checked={isAllSelected}
                            indeterminate={props.value > 0 && props.value < props.options.length}
                        />
                    </ListItemIcon>
                    <ListItemText
                        classes={{ primary: classes.selectAllText }}
                        primary={'Check all'}
                    />
                </MenuItem>
                {props.options.map(option => (
                    <MenuItem key={option} value={option}>
                        <ListItemIcon>
                            <Checkbox checked={props.value.indexOf(option) > -1} />
                        </ListItemIcon>
                        <ListItemText primary={option} />
                    </MenuItem>
                ))}
            </Select>
        </FormControl>
    )
}

export default MultiSelectWithCheckbox
```

**multiSelectWithCheckboxUtil.js**

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'


const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    formControl: {
        width: '100%'
    },
    indeterminateColor: {
        color: '#f50057'
    },
    selectAllText: {
        fontWeight: 500
    },
    selectedAll: {
        '&:hover': {
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08)'
        },
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08)'
    }
}))

const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48
const ITEM_PADDING_TOP = 8
const MenuProps = {
    anchorOrigin: {
        horizontal: 'center',
        vertical: 'bottom'
    },
    getContentAnchorEl: null,
    PaperProps: {
        style: {
            maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5 + ITEM_PADDING_TOP,
        }
    },
    transformOrigin: {
        horizontal: 'center',
        vertical: 'top'
    },
    variant: 'menu'
}

export { useStyles, MenuProps }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated option to display the Uncheck all in the following way

```
const isAllSelected = props.options.length > 0 && props.value.length === props.options.length // here we are checking the condition

<ListItemText classes={{ primary: classes.selectAllText }} primary={isAllSelected ? 'Uncheck all' : 'Check all'} // updated to change the label option
/>
```

**multiSelectWithCheckbox.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Checkbox, InputLabel, ListItemIcon, ListItemText, MenuItem, FormControl, Select } from '@material-ui/core'
import { MenuProps, useStyles } from './multiSelectWithCheckboxUtil'


function MultiSelectWithCheckbox(props) {
    const classes = useStyles()
    const isAllSelected = props.options.length > 0 && props.value.length === props.options.length // here we are checking the condition

    const handleChange = React.useCallback(event => {
        const value = event.target.value
        if (value[value.length - 1] === 'all') {
            props.onChange(props.value.length === props.options.length ? [] : props.options)
            return
        }
        props.onChange(value)
    }, [ props.value ])

    return (
        <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
            <InputLabel id='mutiple-select-label' style={{fontSize: 18}}>{props.label}</InputLabel>
            <Select
                labelId='mutiple-select-label'
                multiple
                value={props.value}
                onChange={handleChange}
                renderValue={React.useCallback(selected => selected.join(', '))}
                MenuProps={MenuProps}
            >
                <MenuItem
                    value='all'
                    classes={{
                        root: isAllSelected ? classes.selectedAll : '',
                    }}
                >
                    <ListItemIcon>
                        <Checkbox
                            classes={{
                                indeterminate: classes.indeterminateColor,
                            }}
                            checked={isAllSelected}
                            indeterminate={props.value > 0 && props.value < props.options.length}
                        />
                    </ListItemIcon>
                    <ListItemText
                        classes={{ primary: classes.selectAllText }}
                        primary={isAllSelected ? 'Uncheck all' : 'Check all'} // updated to change the label option
                    />
                </MenuItem>
                {props.options.map(option => (
                    <MenuItem key={option} value={option}>
                        <ListItemIcon>
                            <Checkbox checked={props.value.indexOf(option) > -1} />
                        </ListItemIcon>
                        <ListItemText primary={option} />
                    </MenuItem>
                ))}
            </Select>
        </FormControl>
    )
}

export default MultiSelectWithCheckbox
```